# Open Excel worksheet - run time error with other macros

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I made a workbook with several sheets for data entry, and I want the index/main sheet to display upon opening every time.

Everything on the internets says to use something like below, but I get a runtime error.

I've made sure the worksheet is named "Attendance Main" and the spelling is correct.

Most troubleshooting issues I've seen are about activating sheets for copying/pasting and other actions. I just want the main sheet to display each time the workbook is opened.

When I create a new workbook, with 2 basic sheets, the macro works. So I am wondering if other macros are interfering with it. However, none of my macros are in "ThisWorkbook", most are in their own modules.

Any help appreciated, and if you need any info from me to narrow down the issue I will try to provide what I can.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 
Worksheets("Attendance Main").Activate
 
End Sub
```

```
Run-time error '1004'
Activate method of Worksheet class failed
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple select code inside the `open` event of `Workbook` works fine.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Sheets("ShowThisFirst").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I get the same runtime 1004 error when I try this.

I am placing this code in the "ThisWorkbook" excel object.

Comment: Can u please try commenting out every other modules in the workbook except this code, and check once again, just to see if the error is happening in this block

Comment: I commented out all 6 modules in my workbook. Same '1004' runtime error. The only macros/code in the workbook are in these 6 modules, 1 per module.

Comment: That is weird. Probably u might have already, but do check if there are any rouge codes in `worksheet events` of each sheet.

Comment: I am not familiar with checking "worksheet events". When I click on all the individual sheets they have no code in them.